# How to represent and serialize a data structure which requires duplicate keys?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm working with a third-party API where you send an order along with an array of options you want to add to the order. Each `Option` has an `OptionId`.

You'd assume the required JSON would look something like this:

```
{  
   //More properties cut for brevity
   "options":[  
      {  
         "optionId":"ID 1"
      },
      {  
         "optionId":"ID 2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Instead, the required JSON actually looks like this:

```
{  
   //More properties cut for brevity
   "options":[  
      {  
         "optionId":"ID 1",
         "optionId":"ID 2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there any way I can represent that data structure in C#? And if yes, is there any way I can tell Json.NET to serialize it the way the API requires?

Comment: To clarify, you need repeated keys of "optionId" in a single object?

Comment: If single object is expected, then it should be manually parsed. https://jsonlint.com/ shows an error with second sample, about duplicated `optionId`

Comment: @John, yeah that's what they want, even though it doesn't appear to be valid Json like Pavel says.

Comment: It's valid ECMA JSON, I believe. I think I've had issues trying to help someone else with this in the past though.

Answer (score 1):

The desired JSON is technically valid, though not recommended because having duplicate keys in an object makes it much more difficult to work with.  I understand this is a third party API, and you don't have any other choice, but I want to make clear to future readers that this is a bad design.

To represent the option IDs in C#, you can use a simple `List<string>`.  You will need to make a custom JsonConverter to write out the desired structure to the JSON.  We'll call it `OptionListConverter`.  So declare the option list as shown below:

```
class Order
{
    [JsonProperty("options")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(OptionListConverter))]
    public List<string> OptionIds { get; set; }
}
```

Then define the `OptionListConverter` like this:

```
class OptionListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<string>);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = (List<string>)value;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var id in list)
        {
            writer.WritePropertyName("optionId");
            writer.WriteValue(id);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can then create the desired JSON like this:

```
var order = new Order
{
    OptionIds = new List<string> { "ID 1", "ID 2" }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order, Formatting.Indented);
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rEYl8p